# How to UPDATE MAX and MIN of a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select, update, group-by

I have a SELECT query of a table with GROUP BY

```
id     col1     category
1      some     1
2      x        1
3      another  1
4      x        2       // should be removed
5      some     2
6      x        2       // should be removed
7      some     3
8      some     3
9      x        4       // should be removed
10     some     4
11     x        4
12     some     4
```

I want to SELECT or UPDATE to remove a row if the first or last (with id order) is `x` (a given value). In other words, I want to skip the first and last row of a category IF `col1='x'`.

I cannot use `JOIN` as it is a `TEMPORARY` table.

Comment: There is no problem in JOINing a temporary table.

Comment: First or last of what?Of category group?In that case why in category 1 the 'middle' is removed?

Comment: @ShlomiNoach in mysql, it is not possible to open a table twice. Thus, it cannot `JOIN`ed to itself.

Comment: @Mihai sorry that was a typo. The first and last rows in a category if `col1='x'`

Comment: @Ali, correct you are. I wasn't thinking about self join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM test GROUP BY category HAVING col='x' 
UNION SELECT MAX(id) FROM test GROUP BY category HAVING col='x')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66613/6)